# In Wolfram network license how to see the list of current users?

Tags: licensing, networking

My company has recently purchased a Wolfram network license. I intend to develop packages for the team. However, a limited number of concurrent users are allowed over the network. How do I see a list of users currently using the Wolfram system?

```
$NetworkLicense
```

> True

Is there a built-in command that can do this from the front end?